# Problem with Service Principal Connection for Azure Data Factory Connector in Powerapps Flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, powerapps, azure-service-principal, service-principal

I've set up a Flow which is activated by a user from a Canvas app. The Flow takes in some parameters and reformats the values and prepares some inputs for the final activity in the Flow which is create a pipeline run in Azure Data Factory (ADF).

The Flow can be started from the Canvas app, without problems, however when the ADF activity runs, it gives a permission error. Originally, this was due to the user not having the required role to create a pipeline run.
Since we don't want all users to have access to ADF and we don't want to have to add them to a role before they can run a pipeline, we set up a service principal for the connection.
The connector I'm using is the built-in ADF-connector in Powerapps Flow.

With the connection now set up with the service principal, we ran the flow again, but still got an error saying:
*The client '**masked-email**' with object id '**masked-object-id**' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines/CreateRun/action' over scope '/subscriptions/**masked-subscription-id**/resourcegroups/ERP_Integrations/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/ErpIntegrationDataFactory/pipelines/BC2AP-PowerApp_00_CallTrigger' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.*

[This is the activity that fails, showing the connection used.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cdvil.png)

What I don't understand here is why the permissions of the users are being checked when connection runs with a service principal. Does anyone know why the user has to have permission, even though I'm connecing using a service principal which has the correct permissions?

First I tried just changing the connection to the service principal connection.
When that failed I tried recreating the activity to avoid any stored data, and adding the newly created connection.

In both these cases I thought the connection would use the credentials of the service principal, but the error I get suggests otherwise.

Comment: I had to give up on this. In the end I had to set up a user group for the users that should be allowed to execute a pipeline, which really shouldn't be necessary when using a service principal.